# How to make protected members not accessible in a "grandchildren" class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, protected

I have the protected variable `var1` in the abstract class AbstractModule

I create `abstract class AbstractActivity : AbstractModule` and use `var1` from the parent class AbstractModule

Now I create `class MyActivity : AbstractActivity` and I want to make `var1` not accessible in the MyActivity class.

How can I do it?

(I can create the protected property, but then I have the same problem)

Comment: You can't. You could, on the other hand, have `AbstractActivity` and `AbstractModule` in the same assembly and make `var1` internal. If you created `MyActivity` in a separate assembly, it wouldn't have access to `var1` (except via reflection).

Comment: Thank you! I need this in two separate assemblies...
But your suggestion with "internal" is very interresting.

Comment: +1 Using shadowing to hide the protected member is icky, but I know of no better way.  Too bad there's not a common-practice way of hiding protected members from derived classes; if there would be no way a derived class could possibly use an inherited member like `MemberwiseClone` correctly, that member shouldn't be exposed to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# does not allow this.  But you can shadow the field in your class `AbstractActivity` by creating one with the same name.  Your class `MyActivity` would then have access to the shadowed field and its value, but not to the field defined in `AbstractModule`.

```
  public class A
  {
     protected bool seeMe;
  }

  public class B : A
  {
     public B()
     {
        base.seeMe = false; // this is A.seeMe
     }

     protected bool seeMe;
  }

  public class C : B
  {
     public C()
     {
        seeMe = true; // this is B.seeMe
     }
  }
```

The above example doesn't prevent code from being written that uses the shadow field. This may cause confusion if the programmer is aware of `A.seeMe` and thinks it is being set.  You can force a compile error when `B.seeMe` is used by decorating it with the Obsolete attribute:

```
  public class B : A
  {
     public B()
     {
        base.seeMe = false; // this is A.seeMe
     }

     [Obsolete("cannot use seeMe", error:true)]
     protected bool seeMe;
  }

  public class C : B
  {
     public C()
     {
        seeMe = true; // this will give a compile error
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you!
I know about `protected new bool seeMe;` and I'm using this but this is ugly ;)

Comment: I added info about using the Obsolete attribute which can make this a little cleaner by forcing an error if the shadow is used.

Comment: With `[Obsolete("cannot use seeMe", error:true)]` is much better!

Comment: @jltrem: How about defining `seeMe` to be some other kind of thing [e.g. an empty static class]?

Answer (score 1):

Same example with above solutions with int value. 
I trying to restrict grand parent field in child class with the same name.

```
  public class MyClass
  {
        protected int myValue = 10;
  }
  public class MyClass1 : MyClass
  {
        protected int myValue = 15;
        public MyClass1()
        {
            base.myValue = 25;
            this.myValue = 11;
        }
  }
  public class MyClass2 : MyClass1
  {
        public void print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("My Value : " + myValue);//this will print 11                
        }
  }
  class Program
  {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass2 myClass2 = new MyClass2();
            myClass2.print();
        }
  }
```

//Restrict grand parent method in child class using sealed keyword

```
public class MyClass
{
    protected virtual void MyMethod()
    {
    }
}
public class MyClass1 : MyClass
{
    // because of sealed method this method will not going to override in derived class.
    sealed override protected void MyMethod() 
    {
    }
}
public class MyClass2 : MyClass1
{
    protected override void MyMethod()//this will give compiler error
    {
    }  
}
```